# Get the records by joining three table that are not in another table

Tags: django, session, join, orm, relation

I'm trying the get the records from the Student table, condition is that the student's primary key do not exist in the From table.(From is used as a relation) table. 
Relation is "student from department"

Model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_no = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    pic_location = models.FileField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class From(models.Model):
    s = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    d = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_no = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email =  models.EmailField()
```

I'm trying to get those records in the list view. And please review whether the way i'm retrieving session variable is good to go in such case??

```
class PendingStudent(ListView):
# Students pending for department approval
    context_object_name = 'pending_students'
    model = From
    template_name = "admin_panel/department/student_detail.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        department = self.request.session.get('username')
        return From.objects.filter(~Q(d__name==department))
```

I've used session, to store what type of user is logged in (student/teacher/department).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to return a queryset which excludes certain values. For that I'd use `.exclude()` instead of `filter` since it's more explict.
You can check that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    department = self.request.session.get('username')
    queryset = From.objects.exclude(d__name=department)
    # In order to print the SQL query you can do this below
    # print(queryset.query.__str__())
    return queryset
```

However, if you want to return many students who are not in the From the table you could do something like:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    return Student.objects.filter(from__d__isnull=True)
```

You can check that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)

Comment: For the second case i need to set the model to student?? Can List View return the model not similar to that one in **model**.

Comment: If you’re overriding the get_queryset you can pass whatever model you want. If you don’t override that method, then Django will use the one you provided above. In any case, it's better to swap the model to `model = Student`

Comment: Thank you!! been digging that problem since 12 hours.

Comment: Can you provide me with the SQL equivalent code please.

Comment: @SuryaBhusal if you assign the queryset to a variable you can print the SQL query. I'm gonna edit my answer so you can see.